# LinkedIn SDK Bitcode iOS 9

Tags: ios, linkedin-api

LinkedIn SDK for iOS still doesn't support Bitcode. When will that be available? Is there any way to workaround this issue on iOS 9?

So far I've tried to disable Bitcode support on my pbxproj file, but that is not a good solution for the whole project.

Comment: You're best off directing your question at LInkedIn themselves.

Disabling bitcode might not be ideal, but Bitcode is not a requirement yet

Comment: @Columbo Thanks, but on their help section they suggest for all questions to be asked on Stackoverflow. https://developer.linkedin.com/support

Answer (score 0):

They just released a compatibility page for iOS 9: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ios-sdk#ios9

Really bad it doesn't have support for Bitcode yet, but that's we have for now.

Answer (score 0):

From the link provided by [Pedro Góes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/368689/pedro-g%C3%B3es):

> Bitcode Support
>
> Bitcode compiling for iOS 9 is supported in version 1.0.6+ of the
>   LinkedIn Mobile SDK for iOS.

So the answer is: LinkedIn SDK supports bitcode.

**EDIT:**

Here is the direct [download link](https://content.linkedin.com/content/dam/developer/sdk/iOS/li-ios-sdk-1.0.6-release.zip) of version 1.0.6.

I have just checked it. **Bitcode is not supported in 1.0.6** as was stated.

Comment: Neither does 1.0.7