# Cant find LinkedIn iOS SDK 1.0.6

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, linkedin-api

I am trying to create a project with LinkedIn ios SDK.
On developer.linkedin.com it says:

> Bitcode compiling for iOS 9 is supported in version 1.0.6+ of the LinkedIn Mobile SDK for iOS.

but when clicking on the 'download SDK' on the same page, it only gives 1.0.3 and 1.0.4 for download.

I definetely need 1.0.6 because of the Enable_bitcode that must be set to YES for my project to compile in Xcode.

Where is this 1.0.6 ??

Comment: Is it an option for you to disable Bitcode for your project? Than you should be able to compile your code.

Comment: unfortunately not as it wil be an Apple Watch app and there it is required

Comment: I've posted the link in my answer

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a link only answer, but the question was about finding a download link:

https://content.linkedin.com/content/dam/developer/sdk/iOS/li-ios-sdk-1.0.6-release.zip

Not sure, if this is a stable version, because I cannot find the download link directly on the start page.

Comment: the link does not contain the 1.0.6 sdk

Comment: OK, sorry than I have no idea. I'll delete my answer

Comment: This question was already asked, but not answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32670210/linkedin-sdk-bitcode-ios-9